# How to find and apply variable substitutions that simplify an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a simple matrix expression.

```
A = ( {
    {Subscript[y, 1], 1},
    {Subscript[y, 2], 1},
    {Subscript[y, 3], 1},
    {Subscript[y, 4], 1}
   } );
result = Inverse[Transpose[A] . A] . Transpose[A]
```

When you run this command, you see the following matrix result:

[image]

Clearly, it's quite large, but could be massively simplified with a change of variables or two.  Such as:

```
r2 = y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2
r1 = y_1  + y_2 +y_3  +y_4
```

Inspired by this question: [How to simplify an expression, using a known term substitution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139466/how-to-simplify-an-expression-using-a-known-term-substitution), I tried using simplify a few different ways that just didn't work:

```
Simplify[result, 
 b == Subscript[y, 1] + Subscript[y, 2] + Subscript[y, 3] + Subscript[ y, 4]]
```

The problem appears to be that Simplify first simplifies the partial fractions, and that leads it down paths where my "simple" substitution becomes difficult/complicated for it to see.  Is there a way to have Mathematica rewrite this expression in terms of the individual y's and r1 and r2?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181818/finding-sub-expressions-that-simplify-larger-formula/182061

Comment: Thank you @Szabolcs, that is a very helpful question/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you avoid using subscripts except for display. Use indexed variables formatted as subscripts.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[y[n_]] = Subscript[y, n];
Format[r[n_]] = Subscript[r, n];

A = {{y[1], 1}, {y[2], 1}, {y[3], 1}, {y[4], 1}};

(result = 
    Inverse[Transpose[A] . A] . Transpose[A] /. {Total[Array[y, 4]] :> r[1],
       Total[-Array[y, 4]] :> -r[1],
       Total[Array[y[#]^2 &, 4]] :> r[2]} // Simplify) // 
  TraditionalForm // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note that the wrappers ([`TraditionalForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) and [`MatrixForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html)) used for display are isolated from the definition of `result` by the use of parentheses.

Comment: Ah, that is very sweet syntax!  Thank you!   That is incredibly helpful for future work.  My comment to Alexi's solution applies to this one as well.

Comment: And for what it's worth, the subscripts question was one I had, but didn't know how to ask.  Thanks!  That is just huge.

Answer (score 2):

Also `Simplify` can do the job, if you feed appropriate `TransformationFunctions`

```
{g1[-Subscript[y, 1] - Subscript[y, 2] - Subscript[y, 3] - Subscript[y, 4]] := -r1, 
 g2[Subscript[y, 1] + Subscript[y, 2] + Subscript[y, 3] + Subscript[y, 4]] := r1, 
 g3[Subscript[y, 1]^2 + Subscript[y, 2]^2 + Subscript[y, 3]^2 + Subscript[y, 4]^2] := r2}; 

Simplify[result, TransformationFunctions -> {g1, g2, g3}] // 
  Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(result /. \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(3\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(4\), \(2\)]\) -> r1 /. 
    Subscript[y, 1] + Subscript[y, 2] + Subscript[y, 3] + Subscript[y,
       4] -> r2 /. -Subscript[y, 1] - Subscript[y, 2] - Subscript[y, 
     3] - Subscript[y, 4] -> -r2) // Simplify

(*  {{(r2 - 4 Subscript[y, 1])/(-4 r1 + r2^2), (
  r2 - 4 Subscript[y, 2])/(-4 r1 + r2^2), (
  r2 - 4 Subscript[y, 3])/(-4 r1 + r2^2), (
  r2 - 4 Subscript[y, 4])/(-4 r1 + r2^2)}, {(
  r1 - r2 Subscript[y, 1])/(4 r1 - r2^2), (r1 - r2 Subscript[y, 2])/(
  4 r1 - r2^2), (r1 - r2 Subscript[y, 3])/(4 r1 - r2^2), (
  r1 - r2 Subscript[y, 4])/(4 r1 - r2^2)}} *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: So, it's disappointing to me, that one has to force the + and - versions of the rules.  i.e. that means this approach is extremely fragile, and any variations of my question will require alternative approaches to address.  I don't see a way around this, I just bring it up in case you do.

Comment: @John It depends on the problem you are facing. In general, usually one can try to find a more compact way to do that, if it is worth doing. In my view, if I do the analytical calculation the best way is the fastest one, rather than a universal one. What can be faster than copy-pasting two-three expressions from your formula? Another story could be if your expression were more complex. Then thinking of a more universal rule pays off.