# Simplify expression by a known expression substitution

Tags: simplifying-expressions

A bit complex than a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139466/how-to-simplify-an-expression-using-a-known-term-substitution), below is a minimal example,

```
eqs1 = a b x'[t]^2 - ac x''[t]
eqs2 = x''[t] - b x'[t] - c == 0
```

I want take `x''[t]` substitute in eqs1, where $eq1= a b \dot{x}^2- ac \ddot{x},~
eq2 = \ddot{x}-b\dot{x}-c$, the output should like $eq1 = ab\dot{x}^2 -ac(b\dot{x}+c)$.

I have try `Simplify[eqs1, eqs2]` but fails. Maybe I should use `SubtractSides` to let `x''[t]` in the left-hand?

If `eq2` is very complicated, eg. `eqs2 = x'[t] x''[t] - b x'[t] - c == 0`, I think it's difficult substitute `x''[t]` of `eq2` into `eq1`.

Any comments very much appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the output should like $eq1 = ab\dot{x}^2 -ac(b\dot{x}+c)$

I am sure there many ways to do this in Mathematica.

One way could be

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqs1 = a*b*x'[t]^2 - a*c*x''[t]
eqs2 = x''[t] - b*x'[t] - c == 0
eqs1 /. First@Solve[eqs2, x''[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not use `First@` above, you'll get same answer but in a list

```
 eqs1 /. Solve[eqs2, x''[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can do `First` on it. It is your choice. The above works, since `Solve` returns results using `->` build into the answer. So all you have to do is just add the `/.` in the front.

In a real program, you should make this more robust of course, by adding additional checks  (such as checking if `Solve` actually solved it, and to check on number of solutions generated and so on.

btw, watch the spaces in Mathematica. You had `ac` it should be `a c` or `a*c`

Comment: Thank you so much, you reminded me that `Solve` will be good choice.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqs1 = a b x'[t]^2 - a c x''[t];
eqs2 = x''[t] - b x'[t] - c == 0;
```

`eqs2` can be solved for `x[t]` using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
sol = DSolve[eqs2, x, t][[1]]

(* {x -> Function[{t}, -((c t)/b) + (E^(b t) C[1])/b + C[2]]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqs2 /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Substituting into `eqs1`

```
expr = eqs1 /. sol // Simplify

(* a b (-c E^(b t) C[1] + (c/b - E^(b t) C[1])^2) *)
```

If the arbitrary constant is set to zero

```
expr /. C[1] -> 0

(* (a c^2)/b *)
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to give a derivative definition:

```
x /: Derivative[n_?(GreaterThan[1])][x] := b x'[#] - c &
```

Then:

```
a b x'[t]^2-a c x''[t]
```

> a b x'[t]^2 - a c (-c + b x'[t])

and:

```
x'[t] x''[t] - b x'[t] - c == 0
```

> -c - b x'[t] + x'[t] (-c + b x'[t]) == 0